# Using fOptions' EuropeanOption function under ClusterEvalQ

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply, lapply, snow

The following is giving me an error. The function evaluated is from the example subsection of the fOptions package pdf (I'm sure it's correct). What am I doing wrong in the parallel processing?

```
require(parallel)    
cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl,require(fOptions)) 
clusterEvalQ(cl,EuropeanOption("call", 100, 100, 0.01, 0.03, 0.5, 0.4))
```

Result:

> Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) :    6 nodes
>   produced errors; first error: no applicable method for
>   'EuropeanOption' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: note that i was merely calling the wrong package (as I use both fOptions and RQuantLib regularly). Should have loaded RQuantLib. So silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function "EuropeanOption" is defined in the "RQuantLib" package, so you should load it on the workers:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, require(RQuantLib))
```

But you should have gotten an "EuropeanOption not defined" error, so something else may be happening. I suggest that you use the makeCluster `outfile=''` option so that you see any error messages generated on the workers.